# Hi i have table. A table having 01 int values for the col rev_levl.I need to add +01 for the current values

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

egg:

```
Rev_lev
   01     //it need to increment like below


Rev_Lev
   01
   02    //lik this
```

i did the below query but it retrieves 2. Help me out
...............................................................

```
select max(0+ rev_level+1)test from [Mettallurgical_WI_ENGG_Upload]
where Part_Number='ABB001'
```

Comment: `select max(rev_level)+1 from [Mettallurgical_WI_ENGG_Upload] where Part_Number='ABB001'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This.

```
    SELECT RIGHT('0'+ISNULL(CAST(max(rev_level)+1 as varchar(2)),''),2)
    from #Mettallurgical_WI_ENGG_Upload
    where Part_Number='ABB001'
```

Comment: @shaliniRavi  :) You live to love your LIFE & Hustle like MAN and I Live to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @MaxValue INT = 0 
 SELECT @MaxValue = MAX(rev_level)
 FROM [Mettallurgical_WI_ENGG_Upload] WHERE Part_Number='ABB001'

 IF ISNULL(@MaxValue,0) = 0 
   SET @MaxValue  = 01
 ELSE 
   SET @MaxValue  = @MaxValue  + 1
```